# How can I see who recently viewed my Facebook profile?

Tags: facebook

Is there any way we can know who viewed our profile recently on Facebook?

I remember Friendster had (has?) this function, but I'm not sure whether Facebook does.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

Taken from Facebook's FAQ:

> Facebook does not provide applications
>   or groups with the technical means to
>   allow people to track profile views or
>   see statistics on how often a
>   particular piece of content has been
>   viewed and by whom. If an application
>   claims to provide this functionality,
>   please report the application by going
>   to the application’s About page  and
>   clicking "Report Application" at the
>   bottom of the page, or by clicking
>   "Report" at the bottom of any canvas
>   page within the application.
>
> Applications you use may ask for
>   permission to access content from your
>   News Feed and Wall. Granting this
>   permission does not allow applications
>   to see who has viewed your profile. It
>   simply allows applications to see
>   which friends have interacted with
>   posts, such as which friends liked or
>   engaged with a particular wall post.

[Source](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=14357)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are majorly three way using that you can easily check that who visited Facebook profile recently, But it will show only these people which recently visited.

Just follow easy steps and find out

1. First of you Need to open your Facebook profile in PC browser.
2. Now just press **Control + U** and open source code.
3. Now go to source code tab and press **Control + F**
4. Find this code **“InitialChatFriendsList.”**

[image]

5. There you will see profile ID.
6. Just pick any ID and past with facebook.com/profile ID
7. You will see that person who visited now

If you need some more way you can [follow this tutorial](https://www.howtoseeks.org/see-who-viewed-my-facebook-profile/) for more mobile and other.
Thanks

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible as facebook does not keep the track of the users that have visited your profile. This is because of the freedom of the user.

Comment: Not true.. where is your source to that?